# The properties of integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Assume $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$.

(a) Prove that if $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$, then the integral of 
$f(x)$ from $a$ to $b > 0$. I tried to apply the Extreme Value Theorem and
into it, but I can not deal  with it  successfully.

(b) Prove that if $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$, and that $f(c) > 0$ for some $c \in [a, b]$, then the integral of
$f(x)$ from $a$ to $b> 0$. I tried to use the
continuity assumption to get that $f(x) > 0$ for some sub-interval $[s, t]$ of $[a, b]$, but I have no idea about the rest of processes.

Could someone help me to finish it? I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the given claim:

For, $m\leq f(x)\leq M$ $\forall$ $x\in [a,b]$, then:

$$m(b-a)\leq\int_a^b f\leq M(b-a)$$

The proof is as follows:

Suppose $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, and $m\leq f(x)\leq M$

Then given some partition $P=\left\{a,b\right\}$,

$$m(b-a)\leq L(P,f)\leq \underline {\int_a^b}f=\int_a^bf=\overline {\int_a^b}f\leq U(P,f)\leq M(b-a)$$

Now consider choosing $m=0$, then we have:

$$0\leq\int_a^b f\leq M(b-a)\Rightarrow \int_a^bf\geq0$$

So, given $f(x)>0$, and $\int_a^bf \ \exists$, then indeed:

$$0\leq\int_a^bf$$

$\mathbf{EDIT}$:

Here is another approach:

We note if $\int_{a}^{b}f \ \exists$, and $\exists \ c\in[a,b]$ such that $f$ is continuous, then $f$ has an antiderivative $F(x)=\int_a^cf$.

Note a separate proof is required for the above claim.

Furthermore, by taking the continuous extension of $f$ onto $\mathbb{R}$, we can thus note that if $f$ is continuous, then infact $f$ has an antiderivative $F(x)=\int_a^bf \ \forall \ x\in[a,b]$.

So let's prove your question, but in a different way:

If $f(x)\geq0 \ \forall \ x\in[a,b]$, and continuous on $[a,b]$, then its antiderivative $F(x) \ \exists$ on $[a,b]$.

Furthermore, by the definition of an antiderivative, $F'(x)=f(x)\geq0\Rightarrow F(x)$ is an increasing (monotone) function on $[a,b]$.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, assuming $b>a\Rightarrow \int_a^bf=F(b)-F(a)\geq0$.

Can you prove the case where $f(x)=0$? In fact, by doing so, this restricts $\int_a^bf$ to be $>0$.

Comment: Thanks！And I have got your idea! How about question 2? Could you give me some processes? Thanks

Comment: Are we assuming f is continuous for the second question? Also if my question helped, don't forget to up vote and verify :D

Comment: okay!And f is also continuous for the second question and my idea is trying to use the continuity assumption to get that f(x)>0f(x)>0 for some sub-interval [s,t]of [a,b]

Comment: Well, if it's continuous, isn't it the same proof as in part a? Seems like my proof satisfies both questions.

Comment: Well, but my instructor require us use two different methods to prove this question.Do you have another method to prove b?

Comment: I added another proof. Keep in mind, this problem has a large variety of solutions, and can also be proven via the definition of continuity. Don't forget to up vote, and cheers!

Comment: Thanks.I have up vote your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Observe that part (a) follows from part (b), so you only need to prove (b). You have the right idea: continuity implies there exists $\delta$ with $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta$).

Now, what can you say about the integral of $f$ on $(c-\delta, c+\delta$)? To finish, what can you say about $\int_{a}^{b}f$ compared to $\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta}f$?

Note: you will have to make sure to choose $\delta$ sufficiently small that $(c-\delta, c+\delta) \subset [a,b]$.

Comment: Could you show me some proof processes for me?I have tried but fails