# Using these two theorems, prove that if a function is positive everywhere its integral is postive

Tags: real-analysis

I've seen a proof of this in other threads, but not one that uses these two facts. The problem is this:

Prove that if $f(x) > 0 $, then $\int_a^b f(x) > 0.$ Using the Extreme Value Theorem and the fact that if $f(x) \geq g(x)$ then $\int_a^b f(x) \geq \int_a^b g(x).$

I have a couple questions with this:

1. The statement to be proven seems obvious to me. If $f(x) > 0$, then $f$ evaluated at each sampling point is always greater than 0, so if the function is continuous then by the strict definition of the integral we should always get a positive sum, should we not? Why is the EVT and the fact offered even suggested?
2. Why is the EVT even needed here? What does it offer us? I can't see it's purpose, seeing as you can't take the integral of single point, and we already know that every value of the function is positive.
3. How do I move from the $\geq$ signs in the fact offered to $>$ for the proof itself? That's another worry.

Comment: I think the EVT is used in the antiderivative of $f$, so you must know that if $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ then any antiderivative is continuous. The problem from this approach is that being $f$ just integrable in $[a,b]$ is not enough to ensure that $F'=f$, so to use the EVT in this way we must assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: EVT is not needed for this proof, but can be used. If you want a different perspective, check this link I posted, it has two different proofs. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233400/the-properties-of-integral/2233507#2233507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from $\ge$ to $>$ is where the EVT comes in. Assuming that $f$ is continuous, it attains its minimum at some point $y \in [0,1]$. Specifically, we must have $f(y) = m >0$. Then $$\int^1_0 f(x) dx \ge \int^1_0 m \, dx = m > 0.$$

Comment: Damn, I see. We're not taking the integral of the point when we take the integral of $m$, instead we're taking the integral of the constant function $f(x) = m$. Thanks.

Comment: The problem does not state that $f $ is continuous!

Comment: @HocNgo That's why I said "assuming $f$ is continuous"; I'm making an additional assumption. Otherwise the property still holds but it is most easily proven in the context of Lebesgue integration by looking at the upper level sets: $E_n = \{x \in [0,1]: f(x) > 1/n \}$. If $f > 0$ everywhere on $[0,1]$, then one of these sets must have positive measure and so we see $$\int^1_0 f(x) dx \ge \int_{E_n} f(x) dx \ge \int_{E_n} \frac 1 n dx = \frac{\lvert E_n \rvert}{n} > 0. $$

Comment: I think this is a desired solution. Thanks.