# Prove that if $f(x) > 0 \; \forall \;x \in (a, b)$, then $\int_a^b{f(x) \; \mathrm{d}x} > 0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Question is in the title. It appears obvious at first glance, but I've got no idea how to prove it.

Edit: I am referring to the Riemann integral.

Comment: Riemann or Lebesgue Integral?

Comment: What is the context? Is it a Riemann integral or a Lebesgue integral? What attempt have you made to answer the question?

Comment: Go to the definition of the integral and see what you can determine

Comment: I gave two solutions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233400/the-properties-of-integral/2233507#2233507

Comment: @MarkPineau: your solution assumes continuity of $f$ which is not the case here.

Comment: For my first solution I nowhere assume $f$ is continuous, only that it is Riemann integrable and bounded, with $f(x)\geq 0$. (The second solution, however, does).